# SQL analogue of SelectMany

Tags: .net, sql, select

Good day!

I'm using mssql and want to do something like SelectMany() is .NET .

I have a table with some codes. Also I have stored function that gets code and returns several records. So, the goal is to select several records from table with codes and transform each record to several records using my function.

For example, table with codes:

```
CODES
  14
  13
  42
  26
  55
```

And my function, for example, returns all code dividers:

```
14 -> 1, 2, 7, 14
```

So I want to write SELECT that gets all codes between 10 and 20 and returns tables with codes and their divisors:

```
CODE DIVISOR
13   1
13   13
14   1
14   2
14   7
14   14
```

Using C# and SelectMany() it can be done like this:

```
codes.Where(code => code > 10 && code < 20).SelectMany(code => GetDivisors(code))
```

But how can it be done using MSSQL?

Comment: Please provide the code for the stored procedure.

Comment: Procedures can't be used in queries.  A user-defined function can.  so this is possible if you can rewrite you procedure to a table user defined query.

Comment: @Andomar, sorry - it was a mistake, it's really a user defined table function. But how it's possible to write a query that selects each code to several records using my function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `outer apply` to run a UDF for each row in the left-hand table:

```
select  c.Code
,       d.Divisor
from    Codes as c
outer apply
        dbo.YourTableUdf(c.Code) as d
```

Comment: Wow, really nice feature. Exactly what I need. Thanks!